# Making client bindings in Haskell servant - ConnectionError

Tags: haskell, servant

I am trying to make client bindings for the News api provided by newsapi.org using the Haskell servant library. I have created the following endpoint:

```
type NewsAPI = "top-headlines" :> QueryParam "country" String :> QueryParam "apiKey" String :> Get '[JSON] TopHeadlines
```

And attempted to call it as follows:

```
topheadlines :: Maybe String -> Maybe String -> ClientM TopHeadlines

api :: Proxy NewsAPI
api = Proxy

topheadlines = client api

query = topheadlines (Just "us") (Just "<api key>")

run3 :: IO ()
run3 = do
  manager' <- newManager defaultManagerSettings
  users <- runClientM query (mkClientEnv manager' (BaseUrl Https "newsapi.org/v2" 443 ""))
  print users
```

I keep getting a connection error that I don't entirely understand how to reason about:

`Left (ConnectionError "HttpExceptionRequest Request {\n  host                 = \"newsapi.org/v2\"\n  port                 = 443\n  secure               = True\n  requestHeaders       = [(\"Accept\",\"application/json;charset=utf-8,application/json\")]\n  path                 = \"/top-headlines\"\n  queryString          = \"?country=us&api_key=90a38fab85c440fa88521e0789248f83\"\n  method               = \"GET\"\n  proxy                = Nothing\n  rawBody              = False\n  redirectCount        = 10\n  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault\n  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1\n}\n TlsNotSupported")`

Not sure why there is no connection. Another set of client bindings I have is working fine.

Comment: As the error says, it seems that TLS is not supported, can you try downgrading your connection to `Http`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a combination of two things:

1. `api_key` should be `apiKey`
2. Rely on `parseBaseUrl`

   ```
   burl  <- parseBaseUrl "http://newsapi.org/v2"
   ```

This worked for me in the sample project I set up.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module Main where

import           Control.Monad.Free
import           Servant.Client.Free

import qualified Network.HTTP.Client                as HTTP
import qualified Servant.Client.Internal.HttpClient as I

import           Network.Wai.Handler.Warp           (run)
import           Servant
import           System.Environment                 (getArgs)

type NewsAPI = "top-headlines" :> QueryParam "country" String :> QueryParam "apiKey" String :> Get '[JSON] String


topheadlines :: Maybe String -> Maybe String -> Free ClientF String
topheadlines = client api


api :: Proxy NewsAPI
api = Proxy


main :: IO ()
main = do
  test


test :: IO ()
test = case topheadlines (Just "us") (Just "API_KEY") of
    Pure n ->
        putStrLn $ "ERROR: got pure result: " ++ show n

    Free (Throw err) ->
        putStrLn $ "ERROR: got error right away: " ++ show err

    Free (StreamingRequest _req _k) ->
        putStrLn $ "ERROR: need to do streaming request" 
    Free (RunRequest req k) -> do
        burl  <- parseBaseUrl "http://newsapi.org/v2"
        mgr   <- HTTP.newManager HTTP.defaultManagerSettings

        let req' = I.requestToClientRequest burl req
        putStrLn $ "Making request: " ++ show req'

        res' <- HTTP.httpLbs req' mgr
        putStrLn $ "Got response: " ++ show res'
```

Comment: The above code is based on the Cookbook code: https://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/v0.15/cookbook/using-free-client/UsingFreeClient.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to fixed the api_key but didn't know to use parseBaseUrl. Do you know why the BaseUrl type constructor wasnt working here?